# Compare MappedTo with raw type in Slick Query

Tags: scala, slick

How do you compare MappedTo[T] with raw T columns?

I have a problem (**Cannot perform option-mapped operation**) with this code:

```
for {
  toEventLink <- Link.linksFromQuery(fromEntity).filter(_.toTable === Event.tableName)
  event <- Event.table.filter(e => e.id === toEventLink.toId)
} yield event
```

In: `e.id === toEventLink.toId` where `e.id` is an ID (extends MappedTo[Long]) and `toEventLink.toId` is a raw Long.

Comment: If there is an extractor (e.g. unapply) defined for MappedTo, then you could use a pattern match instead of the equality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This compiler check is doing what it’s supposed to do (e.g., not let you accidently compare an ID against something that isn’t an ID). But I can totally see why this would be useful (e.g., when migrating a schema to start to used typed keys).

You can use `asColumnOf` to cast a column to the type you want. For example:

```
e => e.id.asColumnOf[Long] === toEventLink.toId
```

There is a an issue open to make a more general solution for this: https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1664